# when reload scene in javafx Maximized did not work

Tags: java, javafx

please help me.
I have following code.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private static Locale locale = new Locale("de", "DE");
    private Scene scene;
    public static Stage stage;

@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        stage = primaryStage;

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.lang", locale);
        fxmlLoader.setResources(bundle);

        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();

        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setMaximized(true);
        stage.setScene(scene);

            stage.show();
}
    public void reload() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.lang", locale));

        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();

        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setMaximized(true);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();

    }
}
```

in my Controller class

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
@FXML
    AnchorPane root;

    @FXML
    private void handleChinese(final ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Main.setLocale(new Locale("zh", "CN")); // change to english
        //JavaFXApplication4.stage.close();
        Main reload = new Main();
        reload.reload();
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleRussian(final ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Main.setLocale(new Locale("de", "DE")); // change to english
        Main reload = new Main();
        reload.reload();
    }
```

it works!, but when change language my window did not show correctly, it means     `stage.setMaximized(true)` did not work, my window did not show as Maximized.

Why does `stage.setMaximized(true)` not work correctly?

Comment: How does your FXMLDocument look like?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of creating a new scene , just set root to the previous scene.

```
public void reload() throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml")); 
    Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
    stage.getScene().setRoot(root);
//        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
//        stage.setMaximized(true);
//        stage.setScene(scene);
//
//        stage.show();
}
```